# javascript number counting

Tags: javascript, numbers, paging

I am slightly stuck on the javascript logic to accomplish this.

Basically

If I give a number (say 30)

I want to show 5 either side.

so

> 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35

That part is easy.

But then I need to handle cases where the number is below 5 (say 3).

What I want to to is,

for every number not shown on the right,
add it to the left

so

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11

But then I need to handle cases where the number is above a (maximum-5) (say maximum = 100, number = 98).

What I want to to is,

for every number not shown on the left,
add it to the right

so

> 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100

But then I need to handle cases where the maximum is below 10 (say number = 3, maximum = 8

What I want to to is,

only show the applicable range

so

> 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8

But I am not sure on the logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ranger(num) {
  //Establish limits and pre/post array storage
  var low = 0, high = 100, howMany = 5;
  var pre = [];
  var post = [];

  //Increment/decrement if appropriate
  for(x=1;x<=howMany;x++) {
    if((num-x) > low) { pre.push(num-x); }
    if((num+x) < high) { post.push(num+x); }
  }
  pre.reverse();

  alert("Before: "+pre+'\nNumber: '+num+'\nAfter: '+post)
}

ranger(7);
ranger(2);
ranger(96);
```

Comment: ranger(10) returns:
"Before: 15,5,14,6,13,7,12,8,11,9"
"Number: 10"
"After: 15,5,14,6,13,7,12,8,11,9"

Comment: @Hail - Fixed, just problem in var declaration. Works perfectly now.

Comment: This method also works, I have accepted this one as it is a function. and I like the fact that pre, num, and post are all seperate variables in the function instead of just a string.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution:

```
function getPages(fromPageNumber) {
    var result = [];
    fromPageNumber= Math.min(94, Math.max(6, fromPageNumber));
    for(var i = -5; i <=5; i++)
        result.push(fromPageNumber + i);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Oops, thanks for spotting that. `fromPageNumber` was `someValue` before I picked a slightly better name.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: center is not defined

Comment: fixed again... should actually try these out first :)

Comment: ...an approach after my own heart... however, the first term to Math.min is likely wrong, it should be the center (95, [96, 97, 98, 99, 100]) with a radius 5: consider `Math.min(max - radius, Math.max(min + radius, x))`, where min and max are inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Tested for all your cases:

```
range = 5;
maximum = 8;
number = 3;
left = right = number;

while(right - left < range*2 ) {
    if (right + 1 <= maximum) {
      right++;
    }
    if (left - 1 > 0 ) {
      left--;
    }
    if (right == maximum && left == 1) {
      break;
    }
}

for(i=left;i<=right;i++) {
  console.log(i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Set up your limits and bounds
var radius = 5.
    middleNumber = 20,
    lowerBound = 1,
    upperBound = 100;

// For the defined (and available range) create an array of valid numbers
var results = [];
for (int i = Math.max(middleNumber - radius, lowerBound);
     i <= Math.min(middleNumber + radius, upperBound);
     i++) {
    results.push(i);
}

// Print out the resulting numbers with spaces in between
console.log(results.join(' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getSequence(num, length)
{
  var min = 0; 
  var max=100;
  Array result;
  for(int i=num-(length/2); i<num+(length/2);i++)
  {
    if(i>min && i< max)
    result.add(i);
  }
  return result;
}
```